# openoffice calc macro access current selection of a validation list

Tags: validation, macros, openoffice.org, calc

i have an openoffice dropdown select using list validation.
the problem is, that the list contains duplicate entries in a flat tree form - like:

```
Test 1
  Subtest
Test 2
  Subtest
```

Now i would like to Convert the selected values to something like "Test 1 - Subtest", "Test 2 - Subtest" etc.

Is there a simple way to do this with an OpenOffice Macro? Or is there at least a way to get the Position of the currently selected Element for a cell.Validation ?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a 'Unique' option that could be activated for not allowing repetitions.